# My Short CFD limit sell triggered at the wrong price, why?

Tags: cfd

So today I did a few CFD trades.

On one, I went short on Kimberly Clark which meant to enter the trade it was classed as 'sell'. I do this as a limit order to minimize risk and calculate projected profits before entering. The price before market opening was 143.68, I put in a limit sell at 143.5, with a stop loss at 150, and a take profit at 135.

However, when the market opened  2 minutes later my sell order executed but at 137.8. This was a massive shock as I was planning to monitor it and manually take profit around 137/138 down from 143.5 (which ofcourse it hit instantly). I only had the take profit there incase it briefly hit higher than I expected.

Why didn't limit orders on my short trigger this way? I thought the point of a limit order was to pick a price. Is this something exclusive to CFD trading I should be aware of?

Declan

Answer (score 2):

This likely was a result of $KMB Kimberly-Clark opening today at 138.84. You weren't able to sell short at 143.5, like you placed the order at, because their market price - at market open - was already below that.

Price data - https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/KMB

Comment: But then my order shouldn't execute?